# create empty array in swift3

Tags: arrays, swift

How to create Empty array in swift when I am creating by this

```
var myArray: NSArray!
```

I am getting error when I am accessing

```
myArray.count
```

it's giving an error

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

and **exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)**

Then how to reslove this issue?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430550/how-to-create-an-empty-array-in-swift

Comment: It doesn't seem like creating an empty array is your only problem. I suggest you read some more about Swift.

Comment: But I was asking for Swift 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick

```
var myArray: NSArray! = []
```

Comment: Thank you, its only work in **Swift3** Others or not working :) (y)

Answer (score 4):

Like this: `var someArray = [String]()`